# Etymology of Modular Representation Theory

Tags: terminology, representation-theory, math-history

What is the origin of the term "Modular representation theory", specifically the modular part?

Comment: It's surely the same "modular" as in "modular arithmetic."

Comment: @QiaochuYuan There are other sources of the word modular, like modular lattices and modules.

Comment: Yes, but modular representation theory is about, y'know, doing representation theory modulo stuff. There is also an actual connection to modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

Modular representation theory is the study of algebras over fields of characteristic $p$. The prime subfield is $\mathbb{F}_p$, where one performs modular arithmetic. This is the source of the term "modular".